# how to change date format in jquery date coming from a datatable

Tags: php, jquery

`aData[8]` is the column number which shows date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

I want to change it to `yyyy-mm-dd` format for validation purpose.

```
var dueDate = new Date(aData[8]);
console.log(aData[8]);
var dt_to = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date(dueDate));
var dueDatetimestamp = dt_to.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to manipulate dates.

You could do something like that with it:

```
moment("13-08-2014", "DD-mm-YYYY").format("YYYY-mm-DD")
```

Comment: '13-08-2014' can this be replaced with dynamic value coming from a datatable like aData[8] is the column number which shows date in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: As long as it's a string following the format set as second parameter it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to achieve :

```
var dateAr = '2014-01-06'.split('-');
var newDate = dateAr[0] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[2];
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/e81metg1/2/)

Comment: '2014-01-06' can this be replaced with dynamic value coming from a datatable like aData[8] is the column number which shows date in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
var str = '13-02-2014';//your format dd-mm-yyyy
var newar = str.split('-');
var tempDate = newar[2] + '-' + newar[1] + '-' + newar[0];
var d = new Date(tempDate);
console.log(d);//date object
console.log(tempDate);//new format yyyy-mm-dd
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/e81metg1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I'm using `jQuery.format.date(value,'date-format')`. But this is a jQuery's plugin available at https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Very simple to use (example from Github) :

```
<script>
  document.write($.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "Test: dd/MM/yyyy"));
  document.write($.format.date("Wed Jan 13 10:43:41 CET 2010", "dd~MM~yyyy"));
</script>
```